# Combine two fields in one and sort by that new combined field

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following Document (... means more properties and getters and setters)

```
@Document
public class Equipment
{
...
private String name;
private String internalManufacturer;
private String externalManufacturer;
...
}
```

And this method in a service, where the name of field is passed (code) and the sorting is set.

```
private void setSorting(String code)
{
    ...
    List<AggregationOperation> pagedAndSortedQuery= new ArrayList<>(baseQuery);
    SortOperation sortOperation = sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, code);
    if (EquipmentsSortingField.MANUFACTURER.getCode().equals(code))
    {
        sortOperation = sort(sortingDirection, "internalManufacturer", "externalManufacturer");
        pagedAndSortedQuery.add(sortOperation);
    }
}
```

I want to sort internalManufacturer and externalManufacturer as if they were one field, because if I do it as in the service, first I get the result sorted internalManufacturers and them sorted externalManufacturers. Important, if externalManufacturer is empty, internalManufacturer is not and viceversa.

For example, I have this in database:

```
Equipment (externalManufacturer: John, internalManufacturer: null)
Equipment (externalManufacturer: null, internalManufacturer: Carlos)
Equipment (externalManufacturer: Ash, internalManufacturer: null)
Equipment (externalManufacturer: null, internalManufacturer: Victor)
```

With my code I get the equipments sorted like this:

```
Equipment (externalManufacturer: null, internalManufacturer: Carlos)
Equipment (externalManufacturer: null, internalManufacturer: Victor)
Equipment (externalManufacturer: Ash, internalManufacturer: null)
Equipment (externalManufacturer: John, internalManufacturer: null)
```

And I like to get them like this:

```
Equipment (externalManufacturer: Ash, internalManufacturer: null)
Equipment (externalManufacturer: null, internalManufacturer: Carlos)
Equipment (externalManufacturer: John, internalManufacturer: null)
Equipment (externalManufacturer: null, internalManufacturer: Victor)
```

In summary, sort both fields as if it was only one field.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generate a new field using `$addFields`, which is the concatenated version of the internal and external manufacturer. Then use this new field for sorting. Something along these lines:

```
private void setSorting(String code)
{
    ...
    List<AggregationOperation> pagedAndSortedQuery= new ArrayList<>(baseQuery);
    SortOperation sortOperation = sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, code);
    if (EquipmentsSortingField.MANUFACTURER.getCode().equals(code))
    {
        AddFieldsOperation addFieldsOperation =
            Aggregation.addFields().addFieldWithValue(
                    "manufacturerString",
                    StringOperators.Concat.valueOf(ConditionalOperators.ifNull("internalManufacturer").then("")).concatValueOf(ConditionalOperators.ifNull("externalManufacturer").then(""))
            ).build();
        sortOperation = sort(sortingDirection, "manufacturerString");
        pagedAnsSortedQuery.add(addFieldsOperation);
        pagedAndSortedQuery.add(sortOperation);
    }
}
```

Note that I have used the new field for sorting, and also added the `addField` stage to the pipeline. Please test it out, I hope you get the idea.

Comment: StringOperators.Concat.concatValueOf does not work -> StringOperators.Concat.valueOf. And besides, the sorting is not working if I do it like that

Comment: Can you add what output you get after you make the change above

Comment: You mean the result? I get the list of equipment without sorting

Comment: Ohh, you mean they just come in the order, in which they are present in the DB.

Comment: Can you check if the pipeline executed on Mongodb, has `$addFields` and `$sort` stage, similar to this https://mongoplayground.net/p/e58oKoBZTzT